# Entity Framework 5.0 - Writing a query for many to many relationship

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-5, one-to-many

I currently have the following Model and DB Context set up for my Entity Framework. 
Relationship is as follows: TableA and TableB both have a many to many relationship.

DBContext:

```
 public partial class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyContext (string connString)
            : base(connString)
        {
            this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

               modelBuilder.Entity<TableA>().HasMany(x => x.TableB).WithMany(
                x => x.TableA).Map(m =>
                {
                    m.ToTable("TableC");
                    m.MapRightKey("B_ID");
                    m.MapLeftKey("C_ID");
                });            

        }

        public DbSet<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
        public DbSet<TableB> TableB { get; set; }


    }
```

Entities:

```
public partial class TableA
{
     public TableA()
     {
         this.TableB  = new List<TableB>();
     }

     [Key]
     public int A_ID { get; set; }
     public string A_Name { get; set; }

     public virtual ICollection<TableB> TableB { get; set; }
}


public partial class TableB
{
   public TableB()
   {
       this.TableA  = new List<TableA>();
   }

   [Key]
   public int B_ID { get; set; }
   public string B_Name { get; set; }

   public virtual ICollection<TableA> TableA { get; set; }
}
```

Note: Because Table C is a Pure Junction Table, Entity Framework does not require a Entity for it.

When I run the following Command:

```
MyContext.TableA.GetList();
```

It returns the list of Table A objects as needed, however for each of the objects in the list it does not include the list of TableB property indicated in the Entity Definition.

Same Behaviour happens when I do

```
MyContext.TableB.GetList();
```

Have I set this up correctly or am I missing some subtle setup?

Comment: It's just a guess, but lazy loading is probably disabled because you have set ProxyCreationEnabled to false. You either need to remove that line or eager-load the related information.

Comment: This appeared to have solved my issue. Please go ahead and submit this as an answer if you like.  Thanks Morten Mertner.

Comment: Thanks, just happy to have helped.

Answer (score 1):

Lazy loading is probably disabled because you have set ProxyCreationEnabled to false. You either need to remove that line or eager-load the related information.